# $H = \{h_i:X_i\to X|i\in M\}$, $h_i$ injective, exists unique family of homomorphisms $g_k$ such that composition is trivial or identity

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

> Let $H = \{h_i:X_i\to X|i\in M\}$ be any injective representation of
>   the module $X$ over $R$ as a direct sum (what?). Prove that there
>   exists a unique family
>
> $$F = \{g_i:X\to X_i| i\in M\}$$
>
> of homomorphisms of modules such that the composition $$g_k\circ
>  h_j:X_j\to X_k$$
>
> is the trivial homomorphism if $j\neq k$ and is the identity
>   homomorphism if $j=k$. Hence, for each $i\in M, h_i$ is a monomorphism
>   and $g_i$ is an epimorphism. Furthermore, we also have
>
> $$X = Im(h_j)\oplus Ker(g_i)$$
>
> for every $i\in M$. The two families $H$ and $F$ are said to
>   constitute a **complete representation of the module $X$ as a direct
>   sum**

What is the mean of "injective representation of the module $X$ over $R$ as a direct sum"? As I understood, since an element of a direct sum is a function from a set of indexes to the union of $X_i$, this particular family $H$ is the one of injective functions to the union of $X_i$. Now I must show that there exists a unique family of homomorphisms $g$ such that

$$g_k\circ f:X\to X_i$$

is trivial if $j\neq k$ and identity if $j=k$

Of course I'd suppose the existence of a family $F$ of members $g_k$ and another $F'$ with members $g_k'$. Also, if $j=k$ the composition is:

$$g_k\circ h_k:X_k\to X_k$$

In order for it to be the identity homomorphism, $(g_k\circ h_k)(a) = a$. The only two ways I can see this are $g_k$ being the inverse of $h_k$, or $h_k$ being trivial and $g_k$ too. I'm stuck here, could somebody help me?

Now, for the direct sum representation, there's a theorem that says:

> If the composition $h=g\circ f$ of two homomorphisms $f:X\to Y$ and
>   $g:Y\to Z$ of modules $X,Y,Z$ over $R$ is an isomorphism, then the
>   following statements hold:
>
> i) $f$ is a monomorphism
>
> ii) $g$ is an epimorphism
>
> iii) The module $Y$ is decomposable into the direct sum of $Im(f)$ and
>    $Ker(g)$

I think I have to use this theorem but there's nothing saying that $g_k$ is a homomorphism, only $h_j$ are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We start with two examples.

**I.** We take the primes $(p_i)_i:=(2,3,5,\dots)$ and the exponents $(\nu_i)_i\in(\mathbb N)_i$ with only a finite number of $\nu_i\ne0$ . Then there exists a homomorphism $f$

$$f((\nu_i)_i):=\prod_i p_i^{\nu_i}$$

into the multiplicative monoid $\mathbb N$. With $(\nu_i)_i+(\mu_i)_i:=(\nu_i+\mu_i)_i$ we have

$$f((\nu_i)_i+(\mu_i)_i)=f((\nu_i+\mu_i)_i)=\prod_i p_i^{\nu_i+\mu_i}=\prod_i p_i^{\nu_i}\cdot\prod_i p_i^{\mu_i}=f((\nu_i)_i)\cdot f((\mu_i)_i)$$

and it is a homomorphism. Because the factorization to primes in $\mathbb N$ is unique, the homomorphism is injective. But for the same reason it is surjective because every number $n\in\mathbb N$ can be uniquely factorized to

$$n=\prod_i p_i^{\nu_i}.$$

But an injective and surjective function is bijective and therefore there exists an inverse $f^{-1}$ such that

$$f^{-1}(n)=(\nu_i)_i.$$

Now we define the injection $\iota_j(\nu_j):=(0,\dots,\nu_j,0,\dots)_i$ into $(\mathbb N)_i$ and the projection $\pi_j((\nu_i)_i):=\nu_j$. We obtain for $h_i(\nu_i):=f\circ\iota_i(\nu_i)=p_i^{\nu_i}$ and $g_j(n):=\pi_j\circ f^{-1}(n)$ just your relation $g_i\circ h_j=\delta_{ij}\cdot id$. The kernel of the homomorphism $g_i$ contains all numbers $n\in\mathbb N$ that are coprime to $p_i$. The image of the homomorphism $h_i$ are all numbers that are an exponent of the prime $p_i$. Therefore the direct sum of the image $h_i$ and the kernel $g_i$ is $\mathbb N$.

**II.** We take a finite commutative (or Abelian) group $G$ and write it as a module $M$ over the principal ideal ring $\mathbb Z$. We factorize the order of the group $\vert G\vert=n=\prod_i p_i^{\nu_i}$ with the above primes. Then we can decompose the module $M$ to modules $M_i$ with elements of order $p_i^k$ for any $k\in\mathbb N$. It is known that

$$M=\oplus_iM_i$$

and there exists an injective homomorphism $f((x_i)_i):=\sum_i x_i\in M$ with $(x_i)_i\in (M_i)$. But because the module $M$ is the direct sum of the modules $M_i$ the homomorphism is also surjective. But then the homomorphism is bijective and there exists an inverse $f^{-1}(x)=(x_i)_i$ for an $x\in M$. Once again we define $\iota_j(x_j):=(0,\dots,0,x_j,0\dots)$ and $\pi_j((x_i)_i):=x_j$. Then the homomorphisms $h_j(x_j):=f\circ \iota_j(x_j)$ and   $g_j(x):=\pi_j\circ f^{-1}(x)$ render the same result $h_i\circ g_j=\delta_{ij}\cdot id$.

In your question above you have an injective homomorphism $H((x_i)_i):=\sum_i x_i=\sum_i\iota_i(x_i)$ as a direct sum. You define $\iota_j(x_j):=(0,\dots,0,x_j,0\dots)_i$ and $h_i(x_i):=H\circ\iota_i(x_i)$. Because the homomorphism $H$ is a representation of the module $M$ this homomorphism must be surjective. Therefore there exists an inverse $H^{-1}(x)=(x_i)_i$ and we define the homomorphism $g_j(x):=\pi_j\circ H^{-1}(x)$ with the projection $\pi_j((x_i)_i):=x_j$. As above we obtain $h_i\circ g_j=\delta_{ij}\cdot id$. The module $M$ can be written as the direct sum of the image of the homomorphisms $h_i$ or as the direct sum of the image of one homomorphism $h_j$ and the kernel of the homomorphism $g_j$ as above.